# VBScript Wildcard telephone number

Tags: vbscript, wildcard

So I have currently the problem that I want to use wildcards on a Telephone number but it seems like I cant use any wildcards in a switch case

```
CallID = 0049555
Select Case CallID
    case "0049*"
        wscript.echo "Case 1"
    case 0049*
        wscript.echo "Case 2"
    case 004955
        wscript.echo "Case 3"
End Select
```

Output: Case 3

Comment: Why would you. Where does it say you even might. Where does it say `*` is anything in VBscript. Use `Instr`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Select Case (InStr(Left(CallID,4), "0049")) OR (InStr(Left(CallID,4), "+49"))
    case 1
        wscript.echo "Case 1"
    case 0
        wscript.echo "Case 0"
    case else
        wscript.echo "Case else"
End Select
```

I solved it now that way. but thanks alot @peter

Comment: If you use this method, why accept the other answer? You can accept your own answers and it is encouraged.

Answer (score 0):

You mean like in Ruby where the following works

```
case "0049555"
when /0048.*/ then print "case 1"
when /0049.*/ then print "case 2"
end
```

I'm afraid that won't work with Vbscript and I have never seen it used in powershellbut there I can't be sure.

You could simulate it in this way..

```
Function evaluate(pattern, string)
  Set re = new RegExp
  With re
      re.Pattern    = pattern
      re.Global     = true
      re.IgnoreCase = true
    End With
    If re.test(string) Then evaluate = true
End Function

CallID = "0049555"
Select Case true
case evaluate("0048.*", CallID)
  wscript.echo "Case 1"
case evaluate("0049.*", CallID)
  wscript.echo "Case 2"
case evaluate("0050.*", CallID)
  wscript.echo "Case 3"
End Select
```

gives Case 2